# Using serde for two (de)serialization formats

Tags: rust, serde

I have successfully used [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) to deserialize and serialize JSON. My setup looks somewhat like this (very simplified):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;
use serde_with::skip_serializing_none;

#[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    bar: Option<Bar>,
    
    baz_quux: Option<u8>,
}

#[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Bar {
    #[serde(rename = "plughXyzzySomeRandomStuff")]
    plugh_xyzzy: Option<u8>
}
```

And then I have implemented `FromStr` and `Display` on `Foo`, which in turn call `serde_json::from_str` and `serde_json::to_string` respectively, to easily (de)serialize the struct.

However, I'd now like to also use `serde_ini` to support (de)serializing INI files as well, to the same Rust data structure. But I can't really figure out how to do that.

The structure itself is simple enough, but my specific problems are with the attributes:

- The keys are named differently in the JSON and INI formats (the JSON format uses the customary camelCase, while the INI doesn't), so I have to solve the `#[serde(rename)]` and `#[serde(rename_all)]` attributes some other way, but I'm not sure where or how.
- `#[serde(flatten)]` [doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/arcnmx/serde-ini/issues/6) with `serde_ini`'s all-string values, which require a `#[serde(deserialize_with="from_str)]"` attribute for all non-string values, but this should obviously only apply to the INI values and not the JSON ones.

So all in all, I guess what I need to do is to re-implement these attributes, or use them conditionally based on what (De)Serializer is used, but I'm stumped on how to do that.

Comment: I understand that `#[serde(alias)]` could be used to deserialize from multiple formats, but not for serializing.

Comment: that not possible, the two format specification are incompatible if there don't use the same key. This should be implemented as two structure.

Comment: This is something that [I was looking into](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/2003) last year; ultimately I ended up following @dtolnay's [advice to pass context to the `Serialize` via a thread local](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/pull/2005#pullrequestreview-617070896).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a limitation of `serde`'s design. The `Deserialize` and `Serialize` implementations are intentionally separated from the `Serializer` and `Deserializer` implementations, which gives great flexibility and convenience when choosing different formats and swapping them out. Unfortunately, it means it is isn't possible to individually fine-tune your `Deserialize` and `Serialize` implementations for different formats.

The way I have done this before is to duplicate the data types so that I can configure them for each format, and then provide a zero-cost conversion between them.

Comment: Thanks! The idea had occured to me; glad it wasn't completely crazy (I had just hoped that there was a more elegant way). But what's the idiomatic way to provide a zero-cost conversion between the two structs?

Comment: @tobiasvl: Assuming the structs have identical layouts, which I think the compiler can only guarantee if they are `repr(C)`, I'd suggest using a [`union`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html).

Comment: @tobiasvl impl from and that all, rust will be smart enough.

Comment: @Stargateur Does that really end up as zero-cost? Interesting! That's what I ended up doing, so that's cool then. A lot of code duplication though (there's basically two of every struct and enum), but if that can't be helped then I'm fine with it. Works like a charm, at least! Thanks!

Comment: @eggyal I'm running into an issue trying to follow this... am I correct in understanding this approach will not work if any field doesn't implement `Copy`? That is pretty restrictive (no `String`s, `Vec`s...)

Comment: @KyleCarow No, that's not correct. There is no need to copy or clone; you generally would write it in such a way that the data is  _moved_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found another approach (documented in https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/2660). My problem was that I wanted to serialize a struct to `csv` and `json`, but `csv` doesn't know how to handle sequences.

The idea is to use a generic parameter for my type who knows how to serialize some special stuff. I use a *newtype* type for `Vec<String>`, so that I can impl `Serialize` for my own. So, my wrapper type looks like this:

```rust
pub trait SerializationType {
    fn serialize<'a, S>(
        items: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
        serializer: S,
    ) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer;
}

pub struct StringSet<T: SerializationType>(Vec<String>, PhantomData<T>);
```

Next, I implement `Serialize` for my type `StringSet<T>`:

```rust
impl<T> Serialize for StringSet<T>
where
    T: SerializationType,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        T::serialize(self.0.iter().map(|s| &s[..]), serializer)
    }
}
```

This could be more specific (not using `Iterator`), because I know that `StringSet<T>` holds a `Vec<String>`, but I wanted to make things more generic.

The next steps are implementations for some serialization specifics:

```rust
pub struct CsvSerialization;
impl SerializationType for CsvSerialization {
    fn serialize<'a, S>(
        items: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
        serializer: S,
    ) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        let v = Vec::from_iter(items).join(",");
        serializer.serialize_str(&v)
    }
}

pub struct JsonSerialization;
impl SerializationType for JsonSerialization {
    fn serialize<'a, S>(
        items: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
        serializer: S,
    ) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        let mut ser = serializer.serialize_seq(None)?;
        for item in items {
            ser.serialize_element(item)?;
        }
        ser.end()
    }
}
```

The usage of this is very simple:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use serde::Serialize;

    use super::{CsvSerialization, JsonSerialization, SerializationType, StringSet};

    #[derive(Serialize)]
    #[serde(bound = "T: SerializationType")]
    struct SampleRecord<T: SerializationType> {
        data: StringSet<T>,
    }

    fn test_data<T>() -> SampleRecord<T>
    where
        T: SerializationType,
    {
        SampleRecord {
            data: StringSet::<T>::from(vec!["a", "b", "c"].into_iter()),
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_serialize_csv() {
        let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(vec![]);
        wtr.serialize(&test_data::<CsvSerialization>()).unwrap();

        let result = String::from_utf8(wtr.into_inner().unwrap()).unwrap();

        assert_eq!(
            result,
            r#"data
"a,b,c"
"#
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_serialize_json() {
        let result = serde_json::to_string(&test_data::<JsonSerialization>()).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(result, r#"{"data":["a","b","c"]}"#);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SampleRecord` has a generic parameter which specifies how to serialize `StringSet` values. Using this parameter, I don't need to create multiple types, because `SampleRecord<CsvSerialization>` is already different from `SampleRecord<JsonSerialization>`. But converting one type into the other is pretty simple.